How can I find duplicate lines among files?
I have a software module which contains some files with same pattern.
<whitespaces>private static final long serialVersionUID = \dL;
How can I find files with the same value?
$ grep -R serialVersionUID
./path/to/Some.java:    private static final long serialVersionUID = 111L;
./path/to/Other.java:        private static final long serialVersionUID = 222L;
./path/to/Another.java:        private static final long serialVersionUID = 111L;

Not that different preceding indent between columns.
Now I want find those files with same value in the second column(private static final ...)?
$ grep -R serialVersionUID | .....
./path/to/Some.java:    private static final long serialVersionUID = 111L;
./path/to/Another.java:        private static final long serialVersionUID = 111L;

Thanks.
This is all I could find, so far...
$ grep -R serialVersionUID | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g' | sort -k 2

I have an improvement, yet it prints the second column only.
$ grep -R serialVersionUID | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g' | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 2 -d


What is your operating system? We need to know that to know what tools you have available. Are you just looking for uniq -D? Try grep -R serialVersionUID | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g' | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 2 -D is that what you need? What is the final output you need here? The file name? The values?

@terdon It's macOS. Thanks

Using any POSIX sort and awk with the OPs original grep -R:
$ grep -R serialVersionUID | sort -k2 -b |
awk '
    { currKey=$0; sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"",currKey) }
    currKey == prevKey { print firstLine $0; firstLine=""; next }
    { prevKey=currKey; firstLine=$0 ORS }
'
./path/to/Another.java:        private static final long serialVersionUID = 111L;
./path/to/Some.java:    private static final long serialVersionUID = 111L;

Regarding [ ][ ] - blanks are already literal in a regexp, you don't need to put them inside a bracket expression. /[ ][ ]*/ is identical to /  */. Maybe you meant to use /[ \t][ \t]*/ to match repetitions of blanks or tabs? You don't need that sed at all though, just add the -b option to sort as I did above to tell it to ignore leading spaces in a field.
The above assumes the file names output by grep -R don't contain white space. If they can then we'd need a different solution that doesn't start with grep -R.

B.E.A.U.tiful!!!
